# Making Read-Only functions for a State in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

I often end up in a situation where it's very convenient to be using the `State` monad, due to having a lot of related functions that need to operate on the same piece of data in a semi-imperative way.

Some of the functions need to read the data in the State monad, but will never need to change it. Using the `State` monad as usual in these functions works just fine, but I can't help but feel that I've given up Haskell's inherent safety and replicated a language where any function can mutate anything.

Is there some type-level thing that I can do to ensure that these functions can only *read* from the `State`, and never write to it?

Current situation:

```
iWriteData :: Int -> State MyState ()
iWriteData n = do 
    state <- get
    put (doSomething n state)

-- Ideally this type would show that the state can't change.
iReadData :: State MyState Int
iReadData = do 
    state <- get
    return (getPieceOf state)

bigFunction :: State MyState ()
bigFunction = do
    iWriteData 5
    iWriteData 10
    num <- iReadData  -- How do we know that the state wasn't modified?
    iWRiteData num
```

Ideally `iReadData` would probably have the type `Reader MyState Int`, but then it doesn't play nicely with the `State`. Having `iReadData` be a regular function seems to be the best bet, but then I have to go through the gymnastics of explicitly extracting and passing it the state every time it's used. What are my options?

Comment: Why don't you just pass the current state into the functions that need it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not hard to inject the `Reader` monad into `State`:

```
read :: Reader s a -> State s a
read a = gets (runReader a)
```

then you could say

```
iReadData :: Reader MyState Int
iReadData = do
    state <- ask
    return (getPieceOf state)
```

and call it as

```
x <- read $ iReadData
```

this would allow you to build up `Reader`s into larger read-only sub-programs and inject them into `State` only where you need to combine them with mutators.

It's not hard to extend this to a `ReaderT` and `StateT` at the top of your monad transformer stack (in fact, the definition above works exactly for this case, just change the type).  Extending it to a `ReaderT` and `StateT` in the middle of the stack is harder.  You basically need a function

```
lift1 :: (forall a. m0 a -> m1 a) -> t m0 a -> t m1 a
```

for every monad transformer `t` in the stack above the `ReaderT`/`StateT`, which isn't part of the standard library.

Comment: It is better to define `read` as `read x = gets (runReader x)`. Then it actually works with the recent definitions of `Reader` and `State` in terms of `ReaderT` and `StateT`.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it answered the question most directly, and is probably going to be what a lot of people are looking for. I really like the other answers though, @bheklilr's answer certainly gives me a lot of food for thought.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend wrapping up the `State` monad in a `newtype` and defining a `MonadReader` instance for it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Reader

data MyState = MyState Int deriving Show

newtype App a = App
    { runApp' :: State MyState a
    } deriving
        ( Functor
        , Applicative
        , Monad
        , MonadState MyState
        )

runApp :: App a -> MyState -> (a, MyState)
runApp app = runState $ runApp' app

instance MonadReader MyState App where
    ask = get
    local f m = App $ fmap (fst . runApp m . f) $ get


iWriteData :: MonadState MyState m => Int -> m ()
iWriteData n = do
    MyState s <- get
    put $ MyState $ s + n

iReadData :: MonadReader MyState m => m Int
iReadData = do
    MyState s <- ask
    return $ s * 2

bigFunction :: App ()
bigFunction = do
    iWriteData 5
    iWriteData 10
    num <- iReadData
    iWriteData num
```

This is certainly more code that @jcast's solution, but it follows the the tradition of implementing your transformer stack as a newtype wrapper, and by sticking with constraints instead of solidified types you can make strong guarantees about the use of your code while providing maximum flexibility for re-use.  Anyone using your code would be able to extend your `App` with transformers of their own while still using `iReadData` and `iWriteData` as intended.  You also don't have to wrap every call to a `Reader` monad with a `read` function, the `MonadReader MyState` functions are seamlessly integrated with functions in the `App` monad.

Comment: And so we get the `mtl` vs. `transformers` philosophical disputation?

Comment: You can make this idea even simpler if you just write the instance for StateT, which is what State already newtypes to: `instance Monad m => MonadReader r (StateT r m) where ask = get; local = withStateT`. That gives you the same property that we can "downgrade" the type signature of iReadData to `MonadReader MyState m => m Int`.

Comment: @ChrisDrost Wouldn't this overlap with the existing instance of `MonadReader r m => MonadReader r (StateT s m)`?  Besides, orphan instances are frowned upon.

Comment: @bheklilr That's a good question; I didn't realize that MonadReader already had an instance for StateT. Yeah, scribbling it out in GHCi reveals that it *will* complain loudly about the overlapping instance even when the underlying monad doesn't fit the constraint for one of the instances.

Answer (score 3):

Excellent answers by jcast and bhelkir, with exactly the first idea I thought of—embedding `Reader` inside `State`.

I think it's worthwhile to address this semi-side point of your question:

> Using the `State` monad as usual in these functions works just fine, but I can't help but feel that I've given up Haskell's inherent safety and replicated a language where any function can mutate anything.

That's a potential red flag, indeed.  I've always found that `State` works best for code with "small" states that can be contained within the lifetime of a single, brief application of `runState`.  My go-to example is numbering the elements of a `Traversable` data structure:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Traversable (Traversable, traverse)

tag :: (Traversable t, Enum s) => s -> t a -> t (s, a)
tag i ta = evalState (traverse step ta) init
    where step a = do s <- postIncrement
                      return (s, a)

postIncrement :: Enum s => State s s
postIncrement = do result <- get
                   put (succ result)
                   return result
```

You don't directly say so, but you make it sound you may have a big state value, with many different fields being used in many different ways within a long-lived `runState` call.  And perhaps it does need to be that way for your program at this point.  But one technique for coping with this might be to write your smaller `State` actions so that they only use narrower state types than the "big" one and then embed these into the larger `State` type with a function like this:

```
-- | Extract a piece of the current state and run an action that reads
-- and modifies only that piece. 
substate :: (s -> s') -> (s' -> s -> s) -> State s' a -> State s a
substate extract replace action =
    do s <- get
       let (s', a) = runState action (extract s)
       put (replace s' s)
       return a
```

Schematic example

```
example :: State (A, B) Whatever 
example = do foo <- substate fst (,b) action1
             bar <- substate snd (a,) action2
             return $ makeWhatever foo bar 

-- Can only touch the `A` component of the state
action1 :: State A Foo
action1 = ...

-- Can only touch the `B` component of the state
action2 :: State B Bar
action2 = ...
```

Note that the `extract` and `replace` functions constitute a *lens*, and there are libraries for that, which may even already include a function like this.