# In Haskell, how to make read-only parameters that depend on ST

Tags: haskell, state, mutability

Context:
When considering the signature of a function in a typical imperative language, some parameters might be denoted as mutable references, some parameters might be denoted as immutable references, some parameters might be seen as simple pure constants.

I am trying to understand how to reproduce this in Haskell, most importantly the mutable/immutable handling of variables that depend on the state.

There are several approaches to manage state in Haskell.
One approach seems to be  via `State`/`StateT`/`MonadState` which fit well with monad transformers. 
Among stateful function parameters, if I want to make it explicit that one should be regarded as immutable inside the function body,  I believe answers to that question: [Making Read-Only functions for a State in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587132/making-read-only-functions-for-a-state-in-haskell) explain well how to do it, by using `Reader` or `MonadReader`.

Another approach to manage state (which I am more interested in that case), is with `ST`. I like `ST` better because, it allows to manage more than just one memory cell at the same time, and it appears to be more performant than `State`.
The problem now is that I don't know how to properly manage a distinction between mutable/immutable stateful variables in `ST`. The `Reader` way does not seem to apply in that case. I have been looking at the `STMonadTrans` package which seems to help make `ST` fit with monad transformers, but I am not sure how to use it.

Question: Do you have a simple example of a function `f` that creates a mutable variable `x` with `newSTRef`, and passes `x` to a function `g`, in an immutable way, that is, in such a way that `g` can read `x` but not modify `x`? If not is there a workaround?

Remark 1: A workaround could be to freeze the mutable variables before passing them to make them pure, however in my case its not acceptable solution because freezing can be either expensive or unsafe, and it is not possible to freeze complex structures quickly such as vectors of vectors. Unsafe coerce is not acceptable either. I am looking for a safe zero runtime cost solution.

Remark 2: Someone said I can just read the reference before going into the function, but this is over simplified answer to my simplified question. In a more general context, it is possible that one cannot `readSTRef` the variable `x` before going into the function `g` because `x` is more complex like a set of mutable arrays.
I am still asking my question in that simple way to try to figure out how to do the general thing on a simple example.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason why `do { xVal <- readSTRef x; let result = fn xVal }` wouldn’t work? `xVal` is just a value, so `fn` can call it but not mutate it, as function parameters cannot be mutated in Haskell.

Comment: You should give an example of what particular situation you're interested in (in an imperative language / pseudocode).

Comment: @jam Given the way you wrote your question, I had assumed that you wanted to prevent the called function `fn` mutating `x` with `writeSTRef`. If so, the code I gave should work. If not, then what did you intend to mean?

Comment: @jam And anyway, if you want to be able to call `readIORef` but not `writeIORef`, then you have an immutable value, and as far as I can see there’s no point in using an `STRef s a` for that rather than just an `a`.

Comment: @bradrn I'm sorry I read too quickly. However I am realizing this is too narrow a use case. I was asking a simple question, to really get an answer to a much more general question. But this question is so over simplified that you just give me an oversimple answer. I'll replace my question with an array or something. What would you do if you ```x``` is more complex like an array, and you want to read some cells in it

Comment: @jam Reading a cell from an array is, generally speaking, a pure operation. Usually I would expect a function `readCell :: Int -> Array a -> a`; then I could define a pure function `fn` using that, and again do `do { array <- readSTRef arrayRef; let result = pureFnUsingReadCell array }`. (1/2)

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), which is quite common when people start learning Haskell. To a question like *how do I mutate state?* the most idiomatic answer would be: *You don't. You find another way to model the problem that better fits the philosophy of Haskell.* That's not to say that you can't mutate state at all in Haskell. There's `ST`, `IORef`, etc. Usually, however, you don't need those.

Comment: (2/2) @jam The only situation in which this wouldn’t work is if you happen to have a mutable array, rather than an immutable array inside a mutable `STRef` — but in that case, I would expect functions to convert the mutable array to an immutable one (like [`freeze`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.4.0/docs/Data-Array-MArray.html#v:freeze)), which would let you do `do { array <- freeze mutArray; let result = pureFnUsingReadCell array }`.

Comment: @bradrn Yes exactly, I have an mutable arrays of mutable arrays which is even worse. I said in my remark 1, I don't like this solution because, freeze takes O(n). So I tried unsafeFreeze which takes O(1), but the problem is i have an array of arrays, so still O(n). So I tried unsafeCoerce, but well unsafeCoerce is really unsafe. It seems that whatever i try with ```ST``` is either unsafe or inefficient. With ```State``` the ```Reader``` is a clean solution.

Comment: @jam Is efficiency really such a big concern that you can’t use O(n) functions? I know next to nothing about performance, especially in Haskell, but I can’t help but wonder if this is a case of overly early optimisation. Maybe try benchmarking your application (e.g. with [`criterion`](http://www.serpentine.com/criterion/)) and see if using `unsafeFreeze` is really too slow to be used.

Comment: @MarkSeemann The problem is my context is very specific and long to expose here. I am trying to implement a dijkstra on graphs. Many standard graph algorithms are usually much more inefficient with immutable structures either in terms of memory/runtime. So i feel i don't have much choice.
But anyway, even without regards to my context, as there is a clean solution for ```State```, I don't see why there should not exist a clean solution for ```ST```

Comment: I think I understand the problem better now @jam — thanks for giving some context! Is there any reason why you can’t just pass the mutable array directly into your function? That loses a bit of type-safety and allows mutation, which certainly is undesirable, but it sounds like it will get the job done.

Comment: @bradrn  I can do that, and I have done that so far and it works though less type safe.  My project is purely personal and explorational, just for fun, there is no urgent deliverable or anything, I am just trying to write standard algorithms in the most general effficient and safe way I can. Thats why I am trying to find safer way to deal with state when its necessary.

Comment: @jam Thinking some more about this, one possible solution I can see is that you could make your own custom wrapper over a mutable array — something like `newtype STArray' p s i e = STArray' (STArray s i e)`. Then define `data Mutation = CanMutate | CantMutate`. Now enabling `{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}`, you can have values of both `STArray' CanMutate s i e` as well as `STArray' CantMutate s i e`. This would let you define a wrapper function `writeArray :: (Ix i) => STArray' CanMutate s i e -> i -> e -> ST s ()` which can only apply to mutable arrays.

Comment: @jam (continued) And `freeze :: STArray' CanMutate s i e -> STArray' CantMutate s i e` simply becomes a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read the novel that is the comments section, but a pattern like

```
newtype ReadOnly s a = ReadOnly (ST s a)

makeReadOnly :: STRef s a -> ReadOnly s a
makeReadOnly = ReadOnly . readSTRef
```

has served me well.  This is a classic trick: if you want a data type to support some operations, just define the data type to be a record of the operations you want to support.  In this case, there is only one.

(As a bonus, it can be seen from this that "read only variables" are highly composable!)